# Where can I ask questions of the form "what services could I use to solve X" questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, recommendation-questions

While spinning up on GCP services, I often find myself wanting to describe a problem and ask for suggestions about which GCP components I might stitch together to solve it. But my questions sometimes get tagged as asking a "what is the best X?", which I understand is against stackoverflow best practices.

Can anyone give me guidance on how to ask these kind of high-level architectural advice questions?

Comment: Essentially, my gut feeling is (on SO)... *you can't*. It's both a recomendation and an off-site resource question.

Comment: Just ask _"How can I accomplish X?"_ and make sure that the problem being solved is reasonably scoped (one thing not seven-in-one), and well-defined (make sure that one thing is clear and unambiguous, i.e. not open to interpretation). If you get an answer that suggests the use of a service, great.

Comment: [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) explains this.

Comment: Also, there is the Software Recommendations SE site.

Comment: Upvoted because reasonable question, not because of any form of agreement with any kind of premise or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it from this angle - where can Stack Overflow realistically *help* you?

Let's start with the problem domain.

> I often find myself wanting to describe a problem and ask for suggestions about which GCP components I might stitch together to solve it.

Stitching together components, or libraries, or pieces of logic is exactly how engineering works today.  So, asking which components you should stitch together to solve a problem isn't something we can readily help with, since solving Your Problem® is one of those things that is undefined to the average passer-by *at best*.  That is to say, **your question is too high up in the clouds for us to make concrete sense of it.**

You instead want to actually **make an attempt** at stitching components together to see if you get what you want.  If you do that but discover that there's a small issue, then that's where we could realistically *help* you to get past that issue.  That's where we provide the most value; if you have something almost working but need help with a few pieces, then we could step in.  We're not equipped to help with high-level, architecture-style questions.